# How to secure S3 static sites that are proxied through nginx using letsencrypt

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, lets-encrypt

I have a load of static sites that need to be secured. They are hosted on S3 using the static site configuration I then proxy the public bucket URL using NGINX to its public facing domain.

How can I use letsencrypt to secure the proxied domains?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? It should as simple as generating a cert on your nginx machine?

Comment: I am having trouble using the NGINX plugin as it needs a web root which I don't have

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you are looking for a way to create a Lets Encrypt SSL cert when you don't have a local website.

```
server {
    listen          80;
    ...

    location ^~ /.well-known {
      allow all;
      default_type "text/plain";
      root /tmp/letsencrypt;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://your-proxied-server;
      ...
    }
}
```

Then use that as your webroot to generate the cert like so:

```
sudo -H /opt/letsencrypt/certbot certonly -a webroot --webroot-path /tmp/letsencrypt  -d your.domain.here
```

It will create a file in that folder then make a request to that file via your website.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem using this:

```
sudo certbot --authenticator standalone --installer nginx --pre-hook "nginx -s stop" --post-hook "nginx"
```